# Bind Multi Line HTML content from JQuery Ajax response

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

This is the part of my html code that binds to the view using a Model object.

```
@if (Model.Comments != null)
            {
                @foreach (var thread in Model.Comments.Threads)
                {
                    <div class="comment-wrap">
                        <div class="comment-head">
                            <div class="subsciber-user" style="background: #DDEFC5">@thread.UserName.Substring(0, 2).ToUpper()</div> @thread.UserName <span>@thread.PostedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")</span>
                            <div class="edit-comment"><img class="comment-edit-img" src="~/images/edit-task.svg"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            @thread.Content
                        </div>
                        @if (thread.Attachment != null)
                        {

                            <div class="comment-attachment">
                                <div class="ca-head">@thread.Attachment.Count() Attachments<i><img class="c-download" src="~/images/download.svg" alt="" /></i></div>
                                <div class="ca-tiles">
                                    @foreach (var item in thread.Attachment)
                                    {

                                        <span><img src="@item.AttachmentUrl" alt="Smiley face"></span>

                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        }
                    </div>

                }
            }
```

My requirement is I want to bind this HTML from a jquery Ajax Success. for that, I created an Ajax call.

```
 var val1 = $('#TaskId').val();
    @*$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Task/GetTaskComments',
            data: { id: val1},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (comments) {

            // here i neeed to bind this Html block using each loop,
            //  here we are getting the same response that we are getting Model.Comments in the above code as json 
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to append the looped Html content from ajax success inside my

```
 <div class="bindComments">

  </div>
```

Comment: oh sorry, it's asp.net core.

Comment: Just use a `for` loop of `$.each()` to loop through the data your method returns and create the html

Comment: And it would be easiest to create a hidden template(s) that you clone in each iteration and then update just the elements you want

Comment: can you please give me one link for referring about this method.

Comment: yeh its right, but one of my main issues is that it contains more than two foreach so when I tried to create this block of HTML from ajax success it's showing some syntax issues(single quotes,double quotes not matching).

Comment: We cannot correct your errors if you do not show us the code you tried